# How to generate date out of three separate columns in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have three columns of data naming: day, month, and year. I need to create a date column from combining these three columns into one in the format of mm/dd/yy. I used '&"/"&' between the columns to make it look like a date format.
Although the result looks like what I want, it is not in date format. Thus, I can't do other calculations on the date column (like I can not use DATEDIF).
I need to know how to combine these three columns into one column of date that actually has 'date' format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `=Date(A1,B1,C1)`, assuming your year is in cell `A1`, month in `B1`, and day in cell `C1`.

or if you want to use the "/", use `=datevalue(B1&"/"&C1&"/"&A1)` (if you have a US date format).